# Where can I view a list of Team Sites which have been created in Office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-groups

If I view the list of Site Collections in the SharePoint Admin console on 365, I can only see the Site Collections which have been created with the '/Sites' managed path.

Am I missing an option to switch a view to see '/Teams' sites?

**Update**
We've run a PowerShell script and have found a list of all the missing site collections - it appears that any site which has been created using the `Group#0` template do not display in the Admin Centre under the `/_layouts/15/online/SiteCollections.aspx` url so I still wonder why this is?

Comment: I updated your question with the comment.  Are these sites created when you create an O365 group?

Answer (score 3):

Just page through the results on `/_layouts/15/online/SiteCollections.aspx` in your admin center.

[image]

If you don't see a paging link, then you have less than 30 site collections and if there are none with teams managed path, then you don't have any.

Based on your update, the modern sites will not show up in the admin center. You have to query Exchange for those. Here is a sample snippet from our PowerShell library the outputs Office Groups that have a provisioned SharePoint site.

```
$Groups = Get-UnifiedGroup -ResultSize Unlimited -SortBy Name
        $returnSites = @()
        $Groups | Foreach-Object {
            $Group = $_
            $GName = $Group.Alias
            $SiteURL = $Group.SharePointSiteUrl
            If($SiteURL -ne $null){
                $site = Get-SPOSite -Identity $SiteURL -Detailed
                $returnSites += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                      GroupName = $GName
                      GroupUrl = $SiteURL
                      CurrentStorage = $site.StorageUsageCurrent
                      StorageQuota = $site.StorageQuota
                      StorageQuotaWarningLevel = $site.StorageQuotaWarningLevel
                      EmailAddress = $Group.EmailAddress
                      DisplayName = $Group.DisplayName
                      Privacy = $Group.AccessType
                      Owners = $Group.ManagedBy
                      Created = $Group.WhenCreated
                      Changed = $Group.WhenChanged
                      DenyPageCustomization = $site.DenyAddAndCustomizePages
                }
            }
        }
        $returnSites
```

**Edit** -

The most recent [SharePoint Online Management shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588) has this built in finally. A simple `get-sposite -limit all -template GROUP#0` will return all groups.

Comment: Which module(s) is needed to run this in PS?

Comment: @wjervis now all you need is the updated SharePoint Online Management Shell, see my updated answer.